# Is pandas / numpy's axis the opposite of R's MARGIN?

Tags: python, r, pandas, numpy

Is it correct to think about these two things as being opposite? This has been a major source of confusion for me.

Below is an example where I find the column sums of a data frame in R and Python. Notice the opposite values for `MARGIN` and `axis`.

In R (using `MARGIN=2`, i.e. the column margin):

```
m <- matrix(1:6, nrow=2)
apply(m, MARGIN=2, mean)
[1] 1.5 3.5 5.5
```

In Python (using `axis=0`, i.e. the row axis):

```
In [25]: m = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]))
In [26]: m.apply(np.mean, axis=0)
Out[26]:
0    1.5
1    3.5
2    5.5
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 4):

Confusion arises because `apply()` talks both about which dimension the apply is "over", as well as which dimension is *retained*.  In other words, when you `apply()` over rows, the result is a vector whose length is the number of columns in the input.  This particular confusion is highlighted by Pandas' documentation (but not R's):

```
axis : {0 or ‘index’, 1 or ‘columns’}
  0 or ‘index’: apply function to each column
  1 or ‘columns’: apply function to each row
```

As you can see, `0` means the index (row) dimension is retained, and the column dimension is "applied over" (thus eliminated).

Put another way, application over columns is `axis=0` or `MARGIN=2`, and application over rows is `axis=1` or `MARGIN=1`.  The `1` values appear to match, but that's spurious: `1` in Python is the second dimension, because Python is 0-based.

Comment: Thanks for the etymology and mnemonics. Unfortunately, R's first dimension still refers to rows (From `help(apply)`: **for a matrix 1 indicates rows, 2 indicates columns**). Is there another way to understand or remember this difference?

Comment: @Heisenberg I'd say the difference is doing the operation for each row vs doing it across rows. In numpy/pandas when we use `sum(axis=0)` we mean take the sum across rows (so it is actually a column wise aggregation).

Comment: @Heisenberg: I've added to my answer in hopes of clarifying that.  Ultimately the way to remember is just to practice it--you will eventually not need to think about it.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. While R is column-major in terms of its memory layout, indices are specified as (row, column), just as in linear algebra. This is exactly the same as MATLAB and Julia. The difference in behaviour is due to the definition of the apply functions, not due to how indexing works.

Comment: The answer needs an edit. The statement "0 means the index (row) dimension is retained" should be "0 means the index (row) dimension is **aggregated**"

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, the "margin" concept in R's `apply` is opposite to the "axis" concept in numpy/panda's `apply` function.

Say we are applying the function `f` to a 2-dimensional array `arr`. The function `f` takes a vector input.

**R**: The `MARGIN` argument indicates which array index of `arr` will be *held fixed* within each call to `f`. So if `MARGIN=1` each call to `f` applies to all of the data with same first array index. This means the function is applied once to each row.

So, `f` is applied to `arr[1,]`, `arr[2,]`, ..., `arr[n,]` in turn, where `n` is the number of rows in `arr`.

**numpy/pandas**: The `axis` argument indicates which array index of `arr` will be *varied* within each call to `f`. So if `axis=0`, for each call to `f`, the first array index is varied to generate an input vector. This means the function is applied once to each column.

So, `f` is applied to `arr[:,0]`, `arr[:,1]`, ..., `arr[:,m-1]` in turn, where `m` is the number of columns in `arr`.

The difference in indexing (0-based for Python, 1-based for R) can be confusing but is not the cause of the discrepancy. I have used the appropriate syntax for each language above.

*Alternative Explanation*

R asks "along which dimensions should the function be applied?". So, indicating *rows* to R means that you want the function applied to each row. Meanwhile numpy/pandas think of its "axes" as indicating directions, like the axes of a graph. So when you tell apply to work along the *row* axis, it figures the row axis is vertical, and it works vertically, applying the function to each *column*.

Answer (score 0):

In both Pandas and R, 'axis' and 'margin' are pretty much synonyms: a data frame has a 'columns' axis or margin going down, and a 'rows' axis or margin going to the right.

Pandas and R's `apply` implementations **differ in what they do with the axis/margin keyword**, as follows.

In R, calling `Rows <- 1; apply(df, Rows, sum)` means

> R: "'Row' is the **shape of the inputs.** Each invocation of *f* gets passed one row as an argument."

```
Rows <- 1
Columns <- 2

df <- data.frame(c1 = 1:2, c2 = 3:4, c3 = 5:6, row.names=c('r1', 'r2'))
df
#    c1 c2 c3
# r1  1  3  5
# r2  2  4  6

apply(df, Rows, sum)
# r1  9
# r2 12
```

In Python, calling `Rows = 0; df.apply(sum, axis=Rows)` means

> Pandas: "'Row' is the **shape of the output.** Every invocation of *f* gets passed one column as an argument."

```
import pandas as pd

Rows = 0
Columns = 1

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'c1': [1, 2], 'c2': [3, 4], 'c3': [5, 6]},
    index=['r1', 'r2']
)
df
#     c1  c2  c3
# r1   1   3   5
# r2   2   4   6

df.apply(sum, axis=Rows)
# c1  c2  c3
#  3   7  11
```